# Redirect Webpage using mod-rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get:

```
www.exampleurl.com/shop/detail.html?id=87&name=oil-iso-46-sae-20
```

to resolve to

```
www.exampleurl.com/shop/87/oil-iso-46-sae-20
```

Should this not work?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /shop/detail.html?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

I've tried adding the -multiview, +followsymlinks etc.

Comment: And your desired new URL doesn't have a `.html` suffix, yet your RewriteRule depends on that.

Comment: id=87 and the .html i missed when typing that out, that my fault.

Comment: even with those in the url, its doesnt work. i get a 404.

Comment: What URL you're entering in browser to test this?

Comment: www.exampleurl.com/shop/87/oil-iso-46-sae-20.html

Comment: so, ive rearranged my .htaccess file and now the url is load, but none of the css is load, nor is the database information.

Comment: we're all good thank you everybody!

i had missed a small line of code in my php file.